# Assign Directory Read/Write Privileges to Azure Service Principal from the command line?

Tags: azure, security, permissions, active-directory

I am trying to provision a user in [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory/) using [Terraform's AzureAD provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/index.html).  At the top of the [`azuread_user` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/user.html), it states:

> **NOTE**: If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must have permissions to `Directory.ReadWrite.All` within the `Windows Azure Active Directory API`.

I have created the Azure Active Directory User using the `az` command line:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Owner" --scopes=$SubscriptionUrl --name $PrincipalName
```

However, this doesn't have `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions, as that would be a fairly insane security risk.

How can I add the `Directory.*` permissions to the Service Principal using the [`az` command line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) (by preference) or even the [Azure Powershell Cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-3.0.0), I would even be willing to craft a WebRequest if that would help me solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

What you need here are the [az ad app permission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#commands) commands.

Here is a complete example (assuming powershell):

```
$apiId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Windows Azure Active Directory 
$apiPermissionsId = "78c8a3c8-a07e-4b9e-af1b-b5ccab50a175" # Directory.ReadWrite.All
$spn = az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Owner" --name blah | ConvertFrom-Json 
az ad app permission add --id $spn.appId --api $apiId --api-permissions ("{0}=Scope" -f $apiPermissionsId)
az ad app permission grant --id $spn.appId --api $apiId
az ad app permission admin-consent --id $spn.appId
```

For reference, Microsoft has [a list](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/06/06/guid-table-for-windows-azure-active-directory-permissions/) of the GUIDs used for various applications.

On some occasions I have been unable to find documentation for the magic GUIDs required for a particular app/permission, in which case I would resort to adding them through the portal manually (Azure Active Directory ➔ App Registrations ➔ Required Permissions) and then reading the JSON manifest back to reveal the required GUIDs which can then be plugged into automation.

Comment: @RichardSlater did this answer, answer your question?

Comment: I haven’t tried it yet, but it was only answered seven hours ago.